# After upgrade of Virtual Box, kernel sources are missing

Tags: 12.10, virtualbox

I did upgrade VirtualBox from 4.1 to 4.2

wheneverver I want to load my Win XP VDI, it gives me the following error:

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (`vboxdrv`) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with `/dev/vboxdrv`. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

```
/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.

I ran the suggested step to reinstall the kernel module, and the log file is as follow:

```
Makefile:181: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:181: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:181: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
```

I still unable to re-run my win virtual XP vdi file.

Anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you don't have the kernel headers installed, dkms needs then to install the Virtual Box kernel drive, to install then run:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Afterwards,

```
/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

should work.

Comment: Hey it works man! I did exactly according your suggestion. why the error doesn't say anything about kernel header? just curious.

Comment: It does. You have highlighted it in bolt in your question ;).

Comment: Came here with the same issues as the OP. It was the 'uname -r' advice that you left that made me check the version of the Kernel headers I had installed. They were not the same version as the Kernel I'm running. Thanks.

Comment: This allows `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` to run; however, it fails with the error
    `Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
Makefile:181: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.`

This can hardly be considered successful...

Comment: @weberc2: Did you run the first command?.

Comment: @JavierRivera Yep.

Comment: Then please ask another question, and add to it the output of the first command. Your error message is complaining about the lack of kernel sources, and the first command should fetch them.

Answer (score 0):

The same may happen in VirtualBox 5. The `vboxdrv` script is now called `vboxadd` (I guess) and the logic is as follow:

```
KERN_VER=`uname -r`
KERN_DIR="/lib/modules/$KERN_VER/build"
if [ -d "$KERN_DIR" ]; then
    KERN_REL=`make -sC $KERN_DIR --no-print-directory kernelrelease 2>/dev/null || true`
    if [ -z "$KERN_REL" -o "x$KERN_REL" = "x$KERN_VER" ]; then
        return 0
    fi
fi
```

So basically you need to make sure that you have installed VBoxGuestAdditions and the kernel sources exists in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build`. If they don't match, the command will fail.

Here is a simple test:

```
$ sudo sh -x /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.0.16/init/vboxadd setup 2>&1 | grep KERN
+ KERN_VER=2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64
+ KERN_DIR=/lib/modules/2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64/build
```

So make sure you install all the dependencies, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get -y install dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```

Then make sure that `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build` points to `/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)`.

And double check that these two commands are matching:

```
$ sudo make -sC /usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r) kernelrelease
2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64
$ uname -r
2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64
```