# Need help installing VirtualBox on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kernel, virtualbox, chromebook, chroot

I am running on chroot and the log file reads :

```
    Uninstalling modules from DKMS
    Attempting to install using DKMS

    Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/5.0.2/source ->
             /usr/src/vboxhost-5.0.2

    DKMS: add completed.
    Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
    Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current 
    Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
```

Help please.

Comment: Suggestion - use https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads and install it manually.  Virtualbox from ubuntu repositories didn't play well with some kernels and `dkms` kept complaining, at least in my case

Comment: "Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again" See  http://askubuntu.com/questions/218320/virtual-box-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

**Install the kernel header files.**

Start the command below to make a check

```
apt-cache policy linux-generic | grep Installed
```

- If you see a version behind `Installed:` like this, with a version number

  ```
  Installed: 3.19.0.26.25
  ```

  then start

  ```
  sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
  ```
- if you see

  ```
  Installed: (none)
  ```

  start

  ```
  sudo apt-get install kernel-headers-$(uname -r)
  ```

Comment: I have the same issue. I got installed (none) and followed your command, but now I get this error : Couldn't find any package by regex 'kernel-headers-3.13.0-74-generic'